# Getting Time for each selenium command

Tags: c#-4.0

How to get the time taken for each selenium command using c# code,Means i want to get the time taken by webpage for HTTP Request and response,as we can see in the firebug->Net->HTML if we do any action.
Please some one suggest me how to record that api call timings.

Thanks,
Eswar

Answer (score 0):

you can use code mentioned below it will return you a dictionary containing performance metrics.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using OpenQA.Selenium;

namespace AutomatedTester.PagePerf
{
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static Dictionary<string,object> WebTimings(this IWebDriver driver)
        {
            var webTiming = (Dictionary<string, object>)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver)
                .ExecuteScript(@"var performance = window.performance || window.webkitPerformance || window.mozPerformance || window.msPerformance || {};
                                 var timings = performance.timing || {};
                                 return timings;");
            /* The dictionary returned will contain something like the following.
             * The values are in milliseconds since 1/1/1970
             * 
             * connectEnd: 1280867925716
             * connectStart: 1280867925687
             * domainLookupEnd: 1280867925687
             * domainLookupStart: 1280867925687
             * fetchStart: 1280867925685
             * legacyNavigationStart: 1280867926028
             * loadEventEnd: 1280867926262
             * loadEventStart: 1280867926155
             * navigationStart: 1280867925685
             * redirectEnd: 0
             * redirectStart: 0
             * requestEnd: 1280867925716
             * requestStart: 1280867925716
             * responseEnd: 1280867925940
             * responseStart: 1280867925919
             * unloadEventEnd: 1280867925940
             */ 
            return webTiming;
        }
    }
}
```